# F-measure of a binary classifier

Tags: proof-writing, machine-learning, data-mining

Prove that the F-measure of any binary classifier is $\leq\dfrac{precision+recall}{2}$

Let $P=precision$ and $R=recall$

I have that the F measure $=\dfrac{2PR}{P+R}$

Note that $precision=\dfrac{tp}{tp+fp}$
 and $recall=\dfrac{tp}{tp + fn}$

where tp = true positive, fp = false positive, tn = true negative and fn = false negative

Answer (score 2):

$F$-measure is merely a [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of precision and recall. It is generally [known](http://ajmaa.org/RGMIA/papers/v2n1/v2n1-10.pdf) that harmonic mean of nonnegative numbers is not more than their arithmetic mean. In particular, it is true for two numbers: precision and recall.

Answer (score 1):

I'll help get you started. Note that $0\le P \le 1$;  $0\le R \le 1$.

$\dfrac{2PR}{P+R} \le \dfrac{P+R}{2}$

$4PR \le (P+R)^2$

$4PR \le P^2+R^2+2PR$

$0 \le P^2+R^2-2PR$

$0 \le (P-R)^2$

From here you can plug in your definitions for $P$ and $R$, and show that the result is at minimum $0$ in the required range (more specifically when P=R, i.e. tp=fn).